# How can I clear the contents of a DIV?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a `div` with the following:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

I use jQuery. When I add something to the contents of the `div`, the `div` doesn't expand in height to fit the contents. Is there some way I can make this happen? I thought adding `overflow: hidden` would solve the problem, but seems not to.

Comment: I am not sure how to post the code as the divs inside my main div are generated with jQuery and don't appear when I do a view source.

Comment: If it's a floating div, make sure it's set to `overflow: auto` and that there's another div following it with `clear:both`. But really you should post more code, it's too hard to understand exactly the problem here.

Comment: This shouldn't be possible, unless you are using `float` on your `<div />`. If you are, you should definitely state that in the question.

Comment: Why would you need to do anything at all? If you just add an emtpy div to the HTML, wouldn't its height be 0 by default? Because it has nothing in it? And as you add content to the div, wouldn't its height expand automatically to accommodate the new stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If contents are floated then `overflow:hidden` (or `auto`) can do it, but that doesn't work in Internet Explorer, however.  For IE, use `zoom:1`.

The best approach is to using something like "clearfix" that solves it cross-browser by adding a class to any element you foresee this problem occurring with.

---

Some good reading:

> http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html/
>
> http://pathfindersoftware.com/2007/09/developers-note-2/

Comment: Thanks for your help and the links. My problem was fixed by using clearfix

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead:

```
overflow: auto
```

Answer (score 1):

set `height:auto;`

i think it seems to work..